# Ripple Animation on a Bitmap instead of View

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-animation, android-bitmap

I have been using bitmap to render small colored circles inside a View. Now I want to show custom Ripples Animation around those circles when tapped.

After searching for sometime through StackOverflow's answers, it is being mostly suggested to wrap those bitmaps inside a VIEW and apply Animations to those views using Android's animation framework.

But problem is, I am already drawing those bitmaps inside a view using the canvas of that view via

`canvas.drawBitmap()`

function. I just want to show ripples centered around those bitmaps when clicked. My Question is, Is there anyway that I can provide ripple or any animation to a bitmap without wrapping them as a View?

```
protected void fill(ILineDataSet set, boolean drawCircleHole,
        boolean drawTransparentCircleHole, int selectedEntryIndex) {

        int colorCount = set.getCircleColorCount();
        int holeColorCount = set.getCircleHoleColorCount();
        circleRadius = set.getCircleRadius();
        circleHoleRadius = set.getCircleHoleRadius();

        for (int i = 0; i < (colorCount > holeColorCount ? colorCount: holeColorCount); i++) {

            Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444;
            Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((int) (circleRadius * 2.1),
                (int) (circleRadius * 2.1), conf);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
            circleBitmaps[i] = circleBitmap;

            //fill colors in the values' circles
            mRenderPaint.setColor(set.getCircleColor(i < colorCount ? i : 0));
            mCirclePaintInner.setColor(set.getCircleHoleColor(i < holeColorCount ? i : 0));

            if (drawTransparentCircleHole) {
                // Begin path for circle with hole
                mCirclePathBuffer.reset();

                mCirclePathBuffer.addCircle(
                        circleRadius,
                        circleRadius,
                        circleRadius,
                        Path.Direction.CW);

                // Cut hole in path
                mCirclePathBuffer.addCircle(
                        circleRadius,
                        circleRadius,
                        circleHoleRadius,
                        Path.Direction.CCW);

                // Fill in-between
                canvas.drawPath(mCirclePathBuffer, mRenderPaint);
            } else {

                canvas.drawCircle(
                        circleRadius,
                        circleRadius,
                        circleRadius,
                        mRenderPaint);

                if (drawCircleHole) {
                    canvas.drawCircle(
                            circleRadius,
                            circleRadius,
                            circleHoleRadius,
                            mCirclePaintInner);
                }
            }

            if (i == selectedEntryIndex) {
                circleBitmaps[i] = getScaledUpBitmap(circleBitmaps[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getScaledUpBitmap(Bitmap bm) {
        //scale bitmap as twice its size
        int width = bm.getWidth();
        int height = bm.getHeight();

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(1.5f, 1.5f);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
        bm.recycle();
        return resizedBitmap;
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a list of circles with position and dimensions? If yes, please share your code to detect touch events on the view and list entries class.

Comment: @Ferran Yes, I manage a list of bitmap array. I have edited the question. Right now, I am sending in the index of a circle selected as an argument to the function fill() and scaling the same bitmap if its index matches. I want to show ripple around that circle bitmap when tapped also & trigger ripple animation after bitmap scaling is done.

Answer (score 0):

An Android Ripple animation is a combination of a growing animation + a fade animation. 
In other words, this is a drawing process and that's why it's not recommended to do it directly on a bitmap.

I have written a class which is a layout that you can use as a touch panel.
This layout, called `RippleLayout`, is extended from `RelativeLayout`. You can use this layout to draw your circles and manage `onTouchListener` event to show a ripple animation on a given point.

RippleLayout.java

```
import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class RippleLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private AnimatorSet mAnimatorSet;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private boolean mStarted;
    private float mX, mY;
    private int mCount = 1;
    private int mDuration = 300;
    private float mRadius = 300;
    private IntRippleView rippleView;

    public RippleLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public RippleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public RippleLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void build() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        List<Animator> animators = new ArrayList<>();
        rippleView = new IntRippleView(getContext());
        rippleView.setCircleRadius(0);
        rippleView.setCircleAlpha(1);
        addView(rippleView);

        ObjectAnimator scaleXAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rippleView, "CircleRadius", 0f, 1f);
        scaleXAnimator.setRepeatCount(0);
        animators.add(scaleXAnimator);

        ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rippleView, "CircleAlpha", 1f, 0f);
        alphaAnimator.setRepeatCount(0);
        animators.add(alphaAnimator);

        mAnimatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        mAnimatorSet.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
        mAnimatorSet.playTogether(animators);
        mAnimatorSet.setDuration(mDuration);
        mAnimatorSet.addListener(mAnimatorListener);
    }

    public void doRipple(float x, float y) {
        doRipple(x, y, mRadius, mPaint.getColor());
    }

    public synchronized void doRipple(float x, float y, float radius, int acolor) {
        if (mStarted)
            mAnimatorSet.end();
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
        mRadius = radius;
        rippleView.bringToFront();
        mPaint.setColor(acolor);
        mAnimatorSet.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        if (mAnimatorSet != null) {
            mAnimatorSet.cancel();
            mAnimatorSet = null;
        }
        mPaint = null;
    }

    private final Animator.AnimatorListener mAnimatorListener = new Animator.AnimatorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) {
            mStarted = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) {
            mStarted = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) {
            mStarted = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
        }

    };

    private class IntRippleView extends View {

        public IntRippleView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        private float CircleRadius = 0;

        public void setCircleRadius(float value) {
            CircleRadius = value;
            invalidate();
        }

        public float getCircleRadius() {
            return CircleRadius;
        }

        private float CircleAlpha = 1;

        public void setCircleAlpha(float value) {
            CircleAlpha = value;
            invalidate();
        }

        public float getCircleAlpha() {
            return CircleAlpha;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            int aColor = Color.RED;
            mPaint.setAlpha((int)(255 * CircleAlpha));
            canvas.drawCircle(mX, mY, mRadius * CircleRadius, mPaint);
        }

    }

}
```

How to use

In an XML layout

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    >

    <com.mcblau.pacerblue.components.RippleLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    >

    </com.mcblau.pacerblue.components.RippleLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In your Activity

```
    container = findViewById(R.id.container);
    container.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // detect here which circle was touch
            // get the center of the circle => mCenterX, mCenterY
            container.doRipple(mCenterX, mCenterY); // ripple animation 
            return true;
        }
    });
```

You can draw your circles directly on RippleLayout or in another one. If you put the `RippleLayout` exactly over your bitmap layout, you can use it as a touch panel. In this case, use the `setOnTouchListener` of your circle's layout.

Use `doRipple(x, y);` or  `doRipple(x, y, radius, acolor);` to set circle radius an ripple color.